# Trying to insert QBO invoice with IPP.NET

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am attempting to insert an invoice into Quickbooks Online using IPP.NET.  The problem seems to be in setting the item.

Here is a snippet of my VB code for the first line, which works fine...

```
Dim qboInvoiceLine1 as new intuit.ipp.data.qbo.invoiceline
qboInvoiceline1.desc="Desc1"
qboInvoiceLine1.amount=10
qboInvoiceLine1.AmountSpecified=True
```

If I add the following code for setting the item, I get an error forming the XML...

```
Dim items1 as List(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Item)=New List(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Item)
Dim item1 as new intuit.ipp.data.qbo.item
item1.id=new intuit.ipp.data.qbo.idtype
item1.id.value="1"
items1.add(item1)
qboInvoiceLine1.Items=items1.ToArray
```

I do not even understand why the item ID seems to be some kind of array or list of items.  One source of documentation suggests there is an itemID property of the invoice line, but this does not seem to be the case.  Can anyone give me code for setting the itemID for an invoice line?

Answer (score 1):

```
ItemsChoiceType2[] invoiceItemAttributes = { ItemsChoiceType2.ItemId, ItemsChoiceType2.UnitPrice,ItemsChoiceType2.Qty  };
object[] invoiceItemValues = { new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QB, Value = "5" }, new decimal(33), new decimal(2) };
var invoiceLine = new InvoiceLine();
invoiceLine.Amount = 66;
invoiceLine.AmountSpecified = true;
invoiceLine.Desc = "test " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
invoiceLine.ItemsElementName = invoiceItemAttributes;
invoiceLine.Items = invoiceItemValues;
invoiceLine.ServiceDate = DateTime.Now;
invoiceLine.ServiceDateSpecified = true;
listLine.Add(invoiceLine);
```

Comment: Some properties in the .NET DevKit are set through the Items/ItemsElementName properties.  For an invoice, these properties are part of the ItemsChoiceType2 enumerator and the value is passed into the same Items array index.